# Updating an Android app

Tags: android

I am getting the following error when i try to install my android app on tablet

```
ERROR:
Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!
Please execute 'adb uninstall com.spundhan.expensetracker' in a shell.
 Launch canceled!
```

---

Comment: If you can mark my answer as correct it will be nice. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It clearly means that you did not installing the application properly so just either try to uninstall by going to `Setting=>manage application=>you application i.e expensetracker` or attached your device to computer and open command prompt and go to your android sdk like-

**D:\android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>adb uninstall com.spundhan.expensetracker**

so it will uninstall your application properly and hope when you try to install it again you will not find any error.

Answer (score 2):

It mean that you already have this app on your tablet. it happens when you install it from eclipse for example and then try to update it from the play store. you will need to uninstall the app and then install it again.  eclipse and play store have different signatures and thats why you cant update an app with a different signature.

Comment: I don't want loose the data by uninstalling.. how to add signatures so that app should update when i install it second time

Comment: you can not do that.  if you install from different places you will have to uninstall.

Answer (score -1):

Yes It's Happen so many time when you have already install your apk on your device or emulator  and then again you try to install the same application from the market or any other media.

so that will try to replace your application . so that will show alert message that ,

"You had already install Example.apk for installation you have to uninstall first."

so , once you uninstall your application it will remove your all data related to your app. So, Hope now you care for this next time.

Comment: how should i update the same app without uninstalling it

Comment: are you testing in emulator or real phone ?

Comment: on real phone...when i do some changes in source code and try to install it rises an error saying different signatures.

Comment: once you uninstall app and launch application newly then after it will show same error ?

Comment: Uninstalling the app will wipe my data which i don't want to loose.

Comment: its Basic thing that if you uninstall your app that it will remove or wipe your data . and if you want more for data then you can store data in external file and when app launch then it will fetch from them.

Comment: Basically when i do some changes in source and install it second time i want my existing app on phone should update by its self without loosing any previously changed data.

Comment: have you ever uninstall your app from emulator ? and check true in wrap content box when you launching your app .